# Android Read USB Gamepad

Tags: android

I'm trying to read buttons pressed on a twin USB gamepad in android.

I tried all the methods available in USB package of android including **bulkTransfer, controlTransfer, requestWait**. but all of them always returns the same thing while pressing the buttons. I even can't get the real name of the device.

I installed USB\BT JoyCenter and it detects the key pressed and also show the name of the gamepad connected. I really can't figure out how to read the gamepad and android documentation doesn't fully cover how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out where the problem is. Actually I print out the byte array directly. I think java print byte memory location instead of it's content. I used a bytes to hex converter and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you might want to do is plug the device into a linux box and type lsusb.  You need to find out what USB Classes are supported by the USB device.  Post your answer here for others to see.

Then you need to determine if Android actually supports this class directly.  If it does then things should be relatively easy (so read the manual).  If not, you may need to use libusb or similar to do the actual low-level interactions.  This would not be an easy path, but if the USB class is supported by libusb you can get there.

Once you know the class you are working with, you may find from the [standard docos](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_20_070113.zip) that you need to turn something "on" before it will start sending the data that you are interested in.

Comment: I found my mistake. But thanks for information. I'm new in USB programming.